# Where can I find Japanese-English (manually) word-aligned corpora?

Tags: nlp, corpora, resource-request, japanese

I'm looking for as many very reliable Japanese-English corpora as possible so I'd like to ask:

- Are there any other manually aligned corpora besides KFFT's and
  Utiyama's?
- What are the most accurate automatically aligned corpora (according to metrics) and how do they compare to manual ones in practice?

Comment: A quick search [returns many such corpora](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Resources_for_Japanese#Multilingual). Do any of these suit your needs?

Comment: The two manual ones are the same and I've rephrased my second question, it was poorly phrased.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention statistical machine translation, so you should probably drop the tag are mention why it's relevant. If it's just the project you're working on but doesn't have a direct bearing on the corpora you're looking for it's best not to include it in my opinion.

Comment: @user2779 What about that Wikipedia corpus? That's manually aligned and isn't one of the two you mentioned. The Tanaka corpus seems to meet your needs too.

Comment: To your edit: Tanaka corpus? I'm looking for words alignments, is there a part of it that's word-aligned?

Comment: @user2779 Ah. I did not see your edit. My apologies.